# How to create semantic maps using OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, opencv, edge-detection

Im working on a school project, where I need create a semantic map from the camera picture. The picture is of an agricultural land. The goal is to create it without the help of CNN or learning methods, just classical methods of detection.

I searched for similar methods and algorithm and this is my code and the result, but the algorithm is not good detecting the edges of the various fields in the image.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import imutils
import argparse
import random as rng
rng.seed(12345)

src = cv.imread('field.jpg')
src = imutils.resize(src, width=600)

# Show source image
cv.imshow('Source Image', src)
src[np.all(src == 255, axis=2)] = 0
# Show output image
cv.imshow('Black Background Image', src)
kernel = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, -8, 1], [1, 1, 1]], dtype=np.float32)
# do the laplacian filtering as it is
# well, we need to convert everything in something more deeper then CV_8U
# because the kernel has some negative values,
# and we can expect in general to have a Laplacian image with negative values
# BUT a 8bits unsigned int (the one we are working with) can contain values from 0 to 255
# so the possible negative number will be truncated
imgLaplacian = cv.filter2D(src, cv.CV_32F, kernel)
sharp = np.float32(src)
imgResult = sharp - imgLaplacian
# convert back to 8bits gray scale
imgResult = np.clip(imgResult, 0, 255)
imgResult = imgResult.astype('uint8')
imgLaplacian = np.clip(imgLaplacian, 0, 255)
imgLaplacian = np.uint8(imgLaplacian)
#cv.imshow('Laplace Filtered Image', imgLaplacian)
cv.imshow('New Sharped Image', imgResult)
bw = cv.cvtColor(imgResult, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, bw = cv.threshold(bw, 125, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY | cv.THRESH_OTSU)
cv.imshow('Binary Image', bw)
dist = cv.distanceTransform(bw, cv.DIST_L2, 3)
# Normalize the distance image for range = {0.0, 1.0}
# so we can visualize and threshold it
cv.normalize(dist, dist, 0, 1.0, cv.NORM_MINMAX)
cv.imshow('Distance Transform Image', dist)
_, dist = cv.threshold(dist, 0.4, 1.0, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
# Dilate a bit the dist image
kernel1 = np.ones((3,3), dtype=np.uint8)
dist = cv.dilate(dist, kernel1)
cv.imshow('Peaks', dist)
dist_8u = dist.astype('uint8')
# Find total markers
_, contours, _ = cv.findContours(dist_8u, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# Create the marker image for the watershed algorithm
markers = np.zeros(dist.shape, dtype=np.int32)
# Draw the foreground markers
for i in range(len(contours)):
    cv.drawContours(markers, contours, i, (i+1), -1)
# Draw the background marker
cv.circle(markers, (5,5), 3, (255,255,255), -1)
cv.imshow('Markers', markers*10000)
cv.watershed(imgResult, markers)
#mark = np.zeros(markers.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
mark = markers.astype('uint8')
mark = cv.bitwise_not(mark)
# uncomment this if you want to see how the mark
# image looks like at that point
#cv.imshow('Markers_v2', mark)
# Generate random colors
colors = []
for contour in contours:
    colors.append((rng.randint(0,256), rng.randint(0,256), rng.randint(0,256)))
# Create the result image
dst = np.zeros((markers.shape[0], markers.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
# Fill labeled objects with random colors
for i in range(markers.shape[0]):
    for j in range(markers.shape[1]):
        index = markers[i,j]
        if index > 0 and index <= len(contours):
            dst[i,j,:] = colors[index-1]
# Visualize the final image
cv.imshow('Final Result', dst)
cv.waitKey()
``



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpE4s.jpg
```

Comment: can you also upload the 'field.jpg' image just like you shared the result?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yirVw.jpg

Comment: @B.Kocis in the previous comment i sent you the link of the picture